# Tensorflow ValueError: Unknown activation function: heaviside

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am VERY new to tensorflow and machine learning, but am trying to make a basic classifier to distinguish between two types of images: healthy strawberries and unhealthy strawberries.

I am referencing code I found in an online tutorial and modifying it to work for my project.

I am getting the following error and can't figure out how to solve this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/StrawberryPython/normalizer.py", line 197, in <module>
    model = vgg_build_model()
  File "D:/StrawberryPython/normalizer.py", line 117, in vgg_build_model
    m.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='heaviside'))
  File "D:\StrawberryPython\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\core.py", line 1161, in __init__
    self.activation = activations.get(activation)
  File "D:\StrawberryPython\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", line 201, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\StrawberryPython\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\activations.py", line 573, in get
    return deserialize(identifier)
  File "D:\StrawberryPython\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", line 201, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\StrawberryPython\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\activations.py", line 532, in deserialize
    return deserialize_keras_object(
  File "D:\StrawberryPython\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 377, in deserialize_keras_object
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Unknown activation function: heaviside
```

Here is the relevant code.  Again, this is my first machine learning project and am completely new to tensorflow, so a simple explanation would be very much appreciated :)

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import os
import sys
import random
import shutil
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet import MobileNet
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json
import cv2

def vgg_build_model():
    set_trainable = False
    m = Sequential()
    conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
    for layer in conv_base.layers:
        if layer.name == 'block_conv1':
            set_trainable = True
        if set_trainable:
            layer.trainable = True
        else:
            layer.trainable = False
    m.add(conv_base)

    # Custom Shallow Dense Network
    m.add(layers.Flatten())
    m.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    m.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    m.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='heaviside'))
    return m

# Set up generators train_gen and val_gen
train_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=10,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    shear_range=0.1,
    zoom_range=0.1,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest')

val_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator()

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
train_dir = os.path.join(dir_path, 'training')
val_dir = os.path.join(dir_path, 'validation')

train_gen = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')

val_gen = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    val_dir,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')

# Establish a callback for overfitting detection
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', mode='max', verbose=0)
callback_list = [es]


# VGG16 Model
# Build the model and train using train_gen and val_gen
model = vgg_build_model()
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

# Train the model using the generator
history = model.fit_generator(train_gen,
                              steps_per_epoch=100,
                              epochs=10,
                              validation_data=val_gen,
                              callbacks=callback_list,
                              validation_steps=32)
model.save('vgg1_strawberry.h5')
```

Comment: TensorFlow/Keras does not have an activation by that name (heaviside), I don't think this code is correct, where did you get that this activation was available?

Comment: Please try again by using `m.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid)` in the last layer of the model for the binary classification.